# DbDataReader or OleDbDataReader,which one to use in this situation?

Tags: c#

I have these requirements , need to write a method that retrieves data form `MS Access` database and it should be

•   read-only

•   able to use the data before the entire data set is retrieved.

•   Minimize the amount of system overhead and the amount of memory usage!

Which type of object should I use , `OleDbDataReader` or`DbDataReader` ?
Thank you.

Comment: `OleDbDataReader` class derived from `DbDataReader` like others. It overrides it's properties and methods. Go for `OleDbDataReader`.

Comment: DbDataReader is base class for OleDbDataReader.  Use OleDbDataReader for an Access database.

Answer (score 0):

**.NET** provides us with the **DataReader** class (**OleDbDataReader**, **OdbcDataReader** and **SqlDataReader**) that is essentially **a type safe read only**, forward only rowset. The differences between the various flavours of DataReaders is in which data access library they use. **SqlDataReader works best with SQL Server**, while the others work best with ODBC and OleDB data srouces.